# Fetching http request with query in Alamofire in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, http, httprequest, alamofire

I'm trying to fetch data from mLab service from my mongodb database. I can make the request successfully from browser and get data with code below.

```
https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/mysignal/collections/Ctemp?q={"member_id":2}&apiKey=2ABdhQTy1GAWiwfvsKfJyeZVfrHeloQI
```

I need to change "member_id" to \"member_id\" to not to get sytax error. The rest of is same. However, It doesn't fetch anything with Alamofire in Swift in iOS. (I also tried it without alamofire, with usual http request but still doesn't work)

If I try it without `{"member_id":2}` It is working. 
I'm doing fetching with below code (not working one);

```
Alamofire.request("https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/mysignal/collections/Ctemp?q={\"member_id\":2}&apiKey=2ABdhQTy1GAWiwfvsKfJyeZVfrHeloQI")
```

I also try to add parameters

```
   let parameters: Parameters = ["member_id": "3"]
Alamofire.request("https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/mysignal/collections/Ctemp?q={\"member_id\":3}&apiKey=2ABdhQTy1GAWiwfvsKfJyeZVfrHeloQI", parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .methodDependent))
```

This is the api document;
http://docs.mlab.com/data-api/

Thank You

Comment: Print how you do request and parse response

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk I add it, sorry.

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk By the way, that code has not any parse response in alamofire. just blank.

Comment: @EmreÖnder You mean when you try `{\"member_id\":2}` this way?

Comment: @NiravD Yes. When I try like that in swift. It gives optional found nil error in direct http request. It doesn't give any error in alamofire just blank page.

Answer (score 4):

Your request should look like that:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
     "q": ["member_id": 2], 
     "apiKey": "2ABdhQTy1GAWiwfvsKfJyeZVfrHeloQI"
]
Alamofire.request("https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/mysignal/collections/Ctemp", method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
```

It is more readable, and also you can easily change the parameters.

Hope it helps

Comment: It is working but It fetches all the datas in that table. Not just member 2.

Comment: @EmreÖnder Try setting `member_id` as Integer not string

Comment: Still fetching all the datas. I also tried to change it 2 as Int but no fix.

Comment: @EmreÖnder  `https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/mysignal/collections/Ctemp?q={"member_id":2}&apiKey=2ABdhQTy1GAWiwfvsKfJyeZVfrHeloQI
` is that request fetch correct data?

Comment: Maybe It is about problem in database cuz It looks like this;{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "58e769c7f36d2865dded591d"
    },
    "id": 44389,
    "value": "50.50",
    "ts": "2017-03-06 22:51:35",
    "sensor_id": "temp",
    "member_id": 3
}

Comment: Yes It is the correct data and It fetches data but all of datas not just member 2

Comment: @k8mil I also try to fetch a values which is string with  "q": ["value" : "29.46"] but still doesn't working.

Comment: @EmreÖnder My answer solves your problem which was: create an Alamofire request based on that link: 
`https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/mysignal/collections/Ctemp?q={"member_id":2}&apiKey=2ABdhQTy1GAWiwfvsKfJyeZVfrHeloQI
` . My answer exactly creates that type of request. I think now you problem is that you don't know how to download some data from API, and I think the reading API documentation could help you.